# GNU Data Language

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, dependencies, gnu

I want to install GNU Data Language(GDL) on Ubuntu 14.04. Can anyone please tell me how to install it and whether I need to download any other software to fulfil all dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is available to install from the Universe repository.  In a terminal window just type:

```
sudo apt-get install gnudatalanguage
```

This will also automatically install any needed dependencies.

You can find out more information about this package on the Ubuntu website [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gnudatalanguage).

Comment: It may be necessary to enable the "Universe" repository first (it isn't usually part of the default sources.list): see [How do I enable the “Universe” repository?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Answer (score 0):

you can easily compile a subset (without Eigen3) of the last version and the CVS snapshot using the script described here http://aramis.obspm.fr/~coulais/IDL_et_GDL/minimum_script4gdl.html

for such kind of numerical software it is often better to stick with the recent version (new features, bugs correction, improvement of perf' ...)

please notice that 3 related packages to GDL have been added in Debian
(astro lib, mpfit, coyote lib)

(message from one of the GDL contributor)